# RethinkDB: How to get data from dictionary field and transform them to lists

Tags: rethinkdb

I have objects that have a following structure:

```
[
  {
    'record': 1,
    'tags': [1, 2],
    'data': {
      '1': 10,
      '2': 15
    }
  },
  ...
  {
    'record': 1,
    'tags': [3, 4, 5],
    'data': {
      '1': 100,
      '2': 150
    }
  }
]
```

How can I get distinct lists of `data`: `[10, ..., 100]` and `[15, ..., 150]` to process each of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all `data` have same key, I proposed this `map-reduce` process.

```
.map(function(doc) {
  return doc('data').keys().map(function(key) {
     return [key, [doc('data')(key)]]
    }).coerceTo('object')  
})


.reduce(function(left, right) {
  return left.keys().map(function(key) {
      return [key, left(key).setUnion(right(key))]
    })
  .coerceTo('object')  
})
```

With your data set, we have:

```
r.expr(
[
  {
    'record': 1,
    'tags': [1, 2],
    'data': {
      '1': 10,
      '2': 15
    }
  },

  {
    'record': 1,
    'tags': [1, 2],
    'data': {
      '1': 19,
      '2': 100
    }
  },


  {
    'record': 1,
    'tags': [3, 4, 5],
    'data': {
      '1': 100,
      '2': 150
    }
  }
]
)

.map(function(doc) {
  return doc('data').keys().map(function(key) {
     return [key, [doc('data')(key)]]
    }).coerceTo('object')  
})


.reduce(function(left, right) {
  return left.keys().map(function(key) {
      return [key, left(key).setUnion(right(key))]
    })
  .coerceTo('object')  
})
```

Which produces:

```
{
    "1": [10, 19, 100],
    "2": [15, 100, 150]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `values` on an object to get an array of values from it: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#values

If not all of the indexes are present as keys, you could write something like `r.range(obj.keys().max()).map(function(i) { return obj(i.coerceTo('string')).default(nil); })`.

Comment: Then I'll get [10, 15] and [100, 150]. But I need a list of all values with key '1' and a list of all values with key '2'

Answer (score 0):

If the `data` fields could be any string, something like this could work:

```
r.db('test')
 .table('test')
 .getAll(1, {index: 'record'})
 .getField('data')
 .concatMap(r.row.coerceTo('array'))
 .group(r.row(0))
 .concatMap([r.row(1)])
 .ungroup()
```

Otherwise, mlucy's suggestion might be used to make it more efficient.

EDIT: on further experimentation, I could not get `obj.keys()` to be faster than `group`.